# Specialization of function for a specific template type

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Consider the following:

```
template <typename TResult> inline TResult _from_string(const string& str);
template <> inline unsigned long long _from_string<unsigned long long>(const string& str) {
    return stoull(str);
}
```

I can call the function as such:

```
auto x = _from_string<unsigned long long>("12345");
```

Now I would like to write another specialization for `vector`s, i.e.:

```
template <typename T> inline vector<T> _from_string<vector<T>>(const string& str) {
    // stuff that should be done only if the template parameter if a vector of something
}
```

so that I can do something like this:

```
 auto x = _from_string<vector<int>>("{1,2,3,4,5}");
```

However, when I compile the function (under MSVC 2015), I get error C2768: "illegal use of explicit template arguments", which makes some sense as I shouldn't be having new template arguments in a specialization.

How can I rewrite the `vector` specialization so that it will work?

Comment: You should definitely read [this article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm) by Herb Sutter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function templates can only be [full specialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization), they can't be [partial specialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization); but class templates can.

```
// primary class template
template <typename T>
struct X {
    static T _from_string(const string& str);
};

// full specialization for unsigned long long
template <>
struct X<unsigned long long> {
    static unsigned long long _from_string(const string& str) {
        return stoull(str);
    }
};

// partial specialization for vector<T>
template <typename T>
struct X<vector<T>> {
    static vector<T> _from_string(const string& str) {
        // stuff that should be done only if the template parameter if a vector of something
    }
};

// helper function template
template <typename TResult>
inline TResult _from_string(const string& str) {
    return X<TResult>::_from_string(str);
}
```

then

```
auto x1 = _from_string<unsigned long long>("12345");
auto x2 = _from_string<vector<int>>("{1,2,3,4,5}");
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/PDBUFM70997)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot partially specialize functions.

You should rarely fully specialize functions.

A far better way to handle this problem is to use overloading.  Overloading on return type just requires an extra arg:

```
template<class T> struct tag_t{constexpr tag_t(){}; using type=T;};
template<class T>constexpr tag_t<T> tag{};

template <typename TResult> inline TResult _from_string(const string& str){
  return _from_string( tag<TResult>, str );
}
```

Now we never specialize `_from_string`, we just overload the 2 arg version.

```
inline unsigned long long _from_string(tag_t<unsigned long long>, const string& str) {
  return stoull(str);
}
```

The above isn't even a template.

```
template <class T, class A>
std::vector<T,A> _from_string(tag_t<std::vector<T,A>>, const string& str) {
  // stuff that should be done only if the target type is a vector of something
}
```

The above is a template, but not a specialization of one.

As a bonus, if you have a custom type `bob` in `namespace foo`, you simply have to write `_from_string( tag_t<bob>, std::string const& )` in `namespace foo`, and something known as 'ADL' will automatically find it in most cases.

Overload based dispatching with tags is clear and simple and lets you customize things in related namespaces.